Aiming for smooth SPA behaviour in Next.js, but navigating back to previous Pages causes full page refresh
I have a Page 1 (Search Page) that contains links to Product 1 and Product 2 (Page 2).
Currently, I’m using the default prefetching behavior (prefetch={undefined} or null) for the links to Page 2.
There’s also a back button on Page 2 that should return the user to Page 1 without reloading it.
While this works correctly with router.back(), I’ve noticed an issue on iPhone devices:
after navigating back and forth multiple times—specifically, from Page 1 to Page 2, then back to Page 1, and finally to a different product (Page 2) before returning to Page 1 again—on the fifth load of the Search Page (Page 1), it performs a full-page refresh.
This results in a broken user experience.
I suspect that this issue may be related to memory constraints due to router caching, which could be exceeded and causing the page to refresh.
Do you have any suggestions? If you need any further adjustments or specific details added, just let me know!
Next.js version: 13.4.12
